# Javascript run function in background regardless the page

Tags: javascript, background

i need to run a function periodically regardless the page where i am. This function will get some data periodically.

I dont think that this works:

```
function myFunc()
{
    //your code
}

//set the interval

setInterval(myFunc,2000) //this will run the function for every 2 sec.
```

Because it works only for the page where I am right now, so if i go to another page, function is not executed anymore.
I would like to write a function that start running when user is at index page and then is called periodically until user close the page.
Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in this function? Because running the same javascript across multiple html pages will not work, but maybe there's a better way to deal with your problem.

Comment: in my function i'll get some data by ajax. Data about a server charge and according to that data i can emit alert mails...

Comment: In this case why is it bad when the function execution stops and starts again when the page loads? Other than that, it would be way more elegant to use websockets / [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to listen to server changes.

Comment: Why is the "timeout" tag used here its nothing to do with timeouts?

Comment: Because i want to do something periodically, despite off being in background. Anyway, you can give me negative reputation ;)

Comment: I don't think the question deserves down votes. It's a fair question to ask.

Comment: @NilsH thanks! i'm proud there is still some sense in this community  :)

Comment: @DavidR I did not give you negative reputation. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` will get slowed down or even stopped if the tab your website is running in is not focused. I cannot see why your call has to be made every two seconds and can not be interrupted by page load. I just want to say, if you're looking for calls being made *exactly* every 2 seconds, `setTimeout` or `setInterval` are not your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a [backend application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) or [cron-job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to do that.

Another way do that would be to make an Ajax-only single page application. I guess twitter uses that model.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible with javascript in the browser. When you navigate away from the page, the script will stop. You have to include a script on every page that initializes this periodical update. Or you could rewrite your application to a "single page application", which seems to be popular nowadays.

Comment: Seems to be the best option

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your doing in the function you may be best to use a JS Worker which will run as a new thread and allow you to continue processing as much as you want in the background without having to worry about JS timeouts.

The main point here is what your asking for is **near enough impossible** within JS unless you use something similar to jQUery and dynamically load your pages in to a div? This would mean you still have the effect (visually) that you changing page but the browser only loads the data in.

Its very easy to in fact to load content in to a DIV using jQuery its:

```
$('#elementoloadid").load("/path/to/load");
```

You could achieve this without using jQuery but will take you longer.

Comment: Why would the page need refreshed if its all dynamic loaded?

Comment: And before you down vote theres no mention of refresh in the question

Comment: I didnt say it did? But if you push the back button you would be going of the page? jQuery can override the back button and forward button as far as i know

Comment: " I would like to write a function that start running when user is at index page and then is called periodically until user close the page. Any idea? " That leaves it open to dynamic or static? He doesn't define whats happening between page open and close and "so if i go to another page" doesnt say how hes going to another page?